# Group by, Over or other SQL tools to get value corresp to Min or Max

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

My here is my table

```
Type | Price | Date
chair| 10    | 04/05/2013
chair| 15    | 03/07/2012
chair| 11    |01/01/2011
sofa | 100   |01/08/2011
sofa | 120   |03/09/2013
sofa | 150   |07/07/2010
```

For each distinct type I would like to pull the latest price, so the result of my query should be

```
Type  | Price | Date
chair | 10    | 04/05/2013
sofa  | 120   |03/09/2013
```

I tried group by and over, but so far no luck

Answer (score 4):

You can use a subquery to get the `max(date)` for each type:

```
select t1.type,
  t1.price,
  t1.date
from yt t1
inner join
(
  select max(date) date, type
  from yt
  group by type
) t2
  on t1.type = t2.type
  and t1.date = t2.date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ff93/3)

Alternatively, you can use `max(date) over (partition ...)` like this:

```
select t1.type,
  t1.price,
  t1.date
from
(
  select max(date) over (partition by type) maxdate, type, price, date
  from yt
  group by type
) t1
where t1.date = t1.maxdate;
```

[SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ff93/8)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER`/`DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Date DESC),
            Type, Price, Date
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT Type, Price, Date
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec1b1/2/0)

`ROW_NUMBER` returns always exactly one record whereas  `DENSE_RANK` returns all records with the latest Date(if there are multiple with the same MAX-Date).

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ff93/5)**

```
SELECT t1.type,
       t1.price,
       t1.date
FROM yt t1
WHERE t1.date = (SELECT max(t2.date)
                 FROM yt t2
                 WHERE t1.type = t2.type)
```

If Max value is not enough:

```
SELECT t1.type,
       t1.price,
       t1.date
FROM yt t1
WHERE t1.date = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.date
                 FROM yt t2
                 WHERE t1.type = t2.type
                 ORDER BY t2.date desc)
```

Result:

```
|  TYPE | PRICE |                         DATE |
------------------------------------------------
|  sofa |   120 | March, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
| chair |    10 | April, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: This is interesting, I guess over or group by type is missing. I do not think we can simply take max.

Comment: Edited answer that whould be just one value for max date.